# Force A MapView To Refresh?

Tags: android, refresh, android-mapview

I've a big problem now, I really need some help, I've spent a week for it, but fail.

1. create a MapActivity (A)
2. start another Activity (B) from (A)
3. start another MapActivity (C) from (B)
4. back (C) -> (B)
5. back (B) -> (A)

The first MapActivity (A) is death, never be redrawn whatever I do (zoom in, zoom out, move)

How to force MapActivity (A) work again?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try mapview.invalidate()?

Comment: I tried
  mMapView.invalidate();
  mMapView.refreshDrawableState();
  mMapView.requestLayout();
  mMapView.forceLayout();

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I too face this issue, try having MapView inside some layout say, MapLayout. And remove MapView from MapLayout in onPause() and add MapView into MapLayout in onResume().

Sample:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(mMapLayout.indexOfChild(mMapView)==-1) mMapLayout.addView(mMapView);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mMapLayout.indexOfChild(mMapView)!=-1) mMapLayout.removeView(mMapView);
}
```

Quite old thread but I wasted 3-4 hrs to solve this. I hope this answer will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this
2 MapActivity can not live at the same time
Just do other solution, kill A then create A when come back